# Can Closed questions be hidden/filtered?

Tags: discussion

I find that a lot of questions in my tagged sets have been closed (normally without answer due to quality issues) - can these be either tagged so the can be filtered, or have some form of core filtering available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring broken windows is a bad idea -- it's important that the community see

1. there is a system of rules here that are enforced; if you ask poorly, your question may be closed too
2. the closed questions, if closed incorrectly, can be peer reviewed, edited for improvements, flagged, or (assuming enough rep) voted to open.

Both of these things are critically important and neither can happen if we hide the "dirty laundry".

Now, if more than 50% of the questions on the home page are closed, then a site has much deeper problems of scope topic and messaging -- but there is no evidence this is the case.

Comment: Sorry, my question is one that was obviously poorly asked/phrased. Your answer is spot on and I agree with it entirely, but surely one can have the choice to _actively_ filter them? (As opposed to the system passively hiding them).

Comment: @seriocomic: The same problems would happen if too many people start actively filter them away!